# Gulp-Uglify Error: unexpected token: name (Quill)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, gulp-uglify

I am trying to get my assets bundling to work but it fails with Quill. 
My `bundle.conf.json`:

```
options: {
    uglify: ['production'], // uglify the resulting bundle in prod
    rev: ['production'], // rev the resulting bundle in prod
    transforms: {
      scripts: lazypipe().pipe(babel, {
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
      )
    }
  }
},
vendor: {
  scripts: [
    "./public/assets/bower_components/quill/quill.js",
    ],
```

I am using babel 6. And the file with error is `quill.js` (the first line):

```
import Quill from './core';
```

The error:

```
[09:34:13] ERROR in custom transforms for 'vendor.scripts':
[09:34:13] Error in plugin 'gulp-uglify'
Message:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/atlas3src/public/assets/bower_components/quill/quill.js: Unexpected token: name (Quill)
Details:
    fileName: /home/ubuntu/workspace/atlas3src/public/assets/bower_components/quill/quill.js
    lineNumber: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything anywhere in your tooling configs that is excluding `node_modules` directories?

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1175#issuecomment-266401537